# How to create new instance of type in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I want to define the type explicitly and then create its instance. The following code explains the problem

```
import * as Immutable from "immutable";

// this works.
let map = new Immutable.Map<string, number>();

// neither works below.
type MapType = Immutable.Map<string, number>;
let map = new MapType();
let map = new MapType;
let map = MapType();
```

Comment: You can't do this. You can define alias only to `Immutable.Map` part (without generic type args)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you define a type it's for compilation time only, it won't be part of the compiled js file, so `new MapType` can not work (because there's no such thing as `MapType` in the js).

You can do this:

```
let ctor = Immutable.Map;
let map = new ctor<string, number>();
```

or this:

```
let ctor: { new(): Map<string, number> } = Immutable.Map;
let map = new ctor();
```

In both cases the `ctor` is not a `type` but an actual variable, something that isn't removed by the compiler, but the compiler will translate this:

```
let ctor: { new(): Map<string, number> } = Immutable.Map;
```

into this:

```
let ctor = Immutable.Map;
```